# Nee If function to get output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a function to get count as 1 or zero for the list

```
NET PREMIUM Par / Non Par   Count
1,065               Term    0
22,400              Term    1
37,213              Par     1
27,936              Par     0
30,000              Non Par 1
25,000              Non Par 0

=IF(OR(AS703="Term",AN703>20000)*AND(AS703="Par",AS703="Non Par",AN703>30000),1,0)
```

Im only getting 0 as answer

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/r28a4Rb - Can you check what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=--(OR(AND(AS703="Term",AN703>20000),AND(OR(AS703="Par",AS703="Non Par"),AN703>=30000))
```

[image]

Comment: you should,  it is term and the value is not greater than 20,000.  Like your example it should be 0.